# Android Clickable AppWidget Disable Sound on Click

Tags: android, android-widget, android-button, android-appwidget, remoteview

I have an AppWidget (part of my app).  I want there to be no sound when the user clicks a button in the widget.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CommonsWare answered it:
This is not a method on RemoteViews, and setSoundEffectsEnabled() is not a RemotableViewMethod, so the literal answer is incorrect. However, android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" in the layout file may work.

setting android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" in the xml layout file does indeed work!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you have to turn off notification sounds (pressing volume down, then selecting settings on it). The click sound is usually created by the OS (Samsung Android will have a click but google Nexus will not). The only other way I can think of is, if the widget is yours, create a custom button that overrides that particular functionality.

Comment: Well, if I could access the view directly, I could:
myButton.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);

But, being a RemoteViews, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: No i meant, is the widget part of your app (you developed it) or are you trying to mute someone elses widget.

Comment: Oh, the AppWidget is mine.  It is part of my app.

Comment: setSoundEffectsEnabled(false) will not always work, Best bet is to remove the functionality via extending the Button and removing that functionality. You will need to go into the source code for that fix though.

Comment: See CommonsWare's answer.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code to disable the click sound,

```
yourbutton.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I cannot access the view directly because it is an AppWidget.

Comment: @NightlyNexus: This is not a method on `RemoteViews`, and `setSoundEffectsEnabled()` is not a `RemotableViewMethod`, so the literal answer is incorrect. However, `android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"` in the layout file may work.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yep, that did it.  I should have thought of that haha.  Setting stuff in xml is the best way to work with RemoteViews.

Comment: I am glad that solved your problem.Credit goes to @CommonsWare

Comment: @CommonsWare regarding `setSoundEffectsEnabled` i have set it to false on one of my button but no effect. it still produce sound. tested on Google Nexus 10

Comment: @CommonsWare problem was with `performClick()` which does not respect the `setSoundEffectsEnabled(false)`. Android's Bad :P